# Cross-Compatible System Time Library

Tags: c++

I am working on a game in OpenGL that requires a random number generator.  I am using the random library, but in order to seed it I need to get the system time.  I would use time.h, but I think that  would only work on Windows.

Is there a built-in library that I could use to get the system time that would work on any OS?  An example would be appreciated.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<time.h>` is portable, but `<chrono>` is generally preferred.

For new code, you should look into `<random>`, which includes an `std::random_device`. You can use this as a seed without dealing with time functions at all (and it'll typically be connected to true random number generator device provided by the OS, so it's normally better than using `time` anyway).

Comment: Where has this been all my life?  (Thank you!)